# Is Legion a playable character?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know Legion is present in Mass Effect 3, provided he survived in the case of an imported save, but will he be a part of my squad or has he been reduced to a supporting character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this entry](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3#Returning_Characters) in the Mass Effect Wiki, it appears that he is only present as a supporting character.

Comment: My interest just dropped a significant amount.

Comment: My original wording may have been too strong, the "Returning Characters" section seems to indicate that Legion will be back in some capacity (not totally ruling him out as a potential squad member but hinting that it's unlikely since he isn't in the "Squad Members" section). I hope that he is back as well, he was one of my favourite characters.

Comment: Despite him being only a supporting character, assuming you make the 'correct' decisions for him, his storyline is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Legion is not a playable squad member in Mass Effect 3.

Answer (score -1):

He isn't a playable character, but depending on the choices you made in ME2, he can join your squad as a companion/teammate. He's one of my favorite characters from ME2.

Answer (score -1):

Legion isn't playable, sorry. He's merely a squad member and if you didn't make certain choices in Mass Effect 2, he'll be replaced by Geth IV.