# Are all "killable" characters from previous games alive if I don't import save data?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So [lots of characters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53692/will-legion-be-a-playable-character) in Mass Effect can live or die and their status is imported if I have Mass Effect 2 save data. Are all of these characters "alive" if I start a fresh game in Mass Effect 3 without importing any data? Or are they not all present in the game as squad mates?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53676/is-there-a-major-gameplay-disadvantage-if-i-dont-import-saves

Comment: Also sort of a subset of my question here (which I don't personally think is too broad): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53526/whats-the-backstory-if-you-dont-import-a-save

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, the only returning squadmates are **Liara** (who can not have died), **Ashley**/ **Kaidan** (one of whom must have died), and **Garrus** and **Tali**, who the game assumes to have lived.

As for other notable life and death descisions for non squad members, the game assumes:

**Wrex** was killed on Virmire.
**Grunt** was never awoken from his tank.
**Samara** died at **Morinths** hands, though **Morinth** does not appear directly either.
**Legion** was never activated.
**Jack** and **Thane** died during the suicide mission.
**Miranda** and **Jacob** survived the suicide mission.
Of the Normandy's crew, only **Joker** and **Doctor Chakwas** survived the suicide mission.

Comment: Wow, non-import games sure are boring.

Comment: Do those characters that are assumed to have died play any role if they didn't (if you imported a save where they didn't)?

Comment: Yes, several of them make appearances, though none will join your squad.

Comment: Morinth can appear during the final mission as an Ardat-Yakshi.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [GameFront article](http://www.gamefront.com/mass-effect-3-psa-what-to-expect-if-you-dont-import-from-me2/), there are significant roster deletions by not importing a ME2 save - you're certainly not getting credit for the "best" ending.

For instance, if you don't import a save:

- **Jack and Thane** will die on the suicide mission
- **Mordin, Jacob, Garrus, Tali and Miranda** are part of the crew at the end of the game and survive the suicide mission.
- **Grunt, Legion, and Samara** are considered to have not been recruited by Shepard.